# What is this line of C code doing for a hash map implementation?

Tags: c, hashmap

At work we have been trying to figure out what this code does, and we feel like it could cause problems. This is a hashmap implementation in C.

```
static thrift_map_node_t *thrift_map_newnode (thrift_map_base_t *m, union keyDataTypes key, void * value, int vsize)

thrift_map_node_t *node;
  int ksize = strlen(key) + 1;
  int voffset = ksize + ((sizeof(void*) - ksize) % sizeof(void*));
  node = malloc(sizeof(*node) + voffset + vsize);
  if (!node) return NULL;
  memcpy(node + 1, key, ksize);
  node->hash = thrift_hash(key);
  node->value = ((char*) (node + 1)) + voffset;
  memcpy(node->value, value, vsize);
return node;
```

The problem we think is here

```
  int voffset = ksize + ((sizeof(void*) - ksize) % sizeof(void*));
```

We think this could produce a negative value, eg -9 % 4 = -1 in C.

a work around or any help to what this is attempting to do would be nice.

Comment: size_t is unsigned though

Comment: The value of `ksize` depends on [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) which will *never* return a negative value (unless you have *undefined behavior*). Even if the result of the `%` operator is negative, it will never be larger (or smaller depending on how you look at it) than `-ksize`which means `voffset` will always be a non-negative number.

Comment: Also, you should probably start to use unsigned integer types for any value that should not be negative.

Comment: In the example you have, ksize will be 17 (pointer size being 8), so the final result will be 16.

Comment: `((X - ksize) % X)` is always  smaller than `ksize`.

Comment: voffset is used to re-align the value in the buffer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Not if X is negative (which can not be the case here)

Comment: @KamiKaze right, I forgot to mention this. Thanks.

Comment: Try `voffset = ksize + (sizeof(*node) + ksize + sizeof(void*) - 1) % sizeof(void*);` The part after `ksize +` is the padding required to align to a `sizeof(void*)` boundary.

Comment: FYI: code from https://github.com/rxi/map/blob/master/src/map.c

Comment: "We think this could produce a negative value, eg -9 % 4 = -1 in C." -- how about you verify that?

Comment: Why don't you just call malloc three times (one for the `node`, oen for `node->value` and one to save the text (currently stored not so intuitively at `node + 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot **ever** produce a negative value *if* `size_t` has rank higher than or equal to `int` (and it does except perhaps on some really oddish 16-bit addressing system with 32-bit integers), because then

```
sizeof (void*) - ksize
```

will be of type `size_t` that is an unsigned type and always positive. Hence if void pointer is 8 bytes wide and ksize is 17, the result of subtraction is `(size_t)-9`, or 18446744073709551607 on a 64-bit machine. That modulo 8 is 7, which added to 17 will result in 24, which is a multiple of `sizeof (void *)`.

However, this relies on the `sizeof (void *)` being a *power of 2*, hence it would still be better if you used

```
sizeof (void*) - (ksize + sizeof (void*)) % sizeof (void *)
```

for the padding as this avoids the negative numbers altogether

---

It is true though that *would* the result subtraction be *signed*, since C99 the modulo would be always negative: `(-3) % 4` is `-3` for example.

BTW, the code should not use `sizeof (void *)`, but `_Alignof (void *)`.

---

There is still one more dubious thing in the code. Suppose someone can actually feed in a string that is over 2 GiB in length - then a signed overflow occurs on majority of platforms and that is not going to be pretty!

Comment: It's ok if the rank of `size_t` is  greater than *or equal to* that of `int`, no? (Another possible infractor: size_t is a custom 24-bit type, int is 32 bits. This example comes up all the time in "what ifs" although I don't know if it ever existed outside of the imagination.)

Comment: @rici fixed. 24-bit `size_t` hardly makes any sense... must be some machine where CHAR_BIT == 12 ;)

Comment: Also, looking at your comment about depending on `sizeof(void*)` being a power of two, it occurs to me that what they're trying to do is pad to alignment. So they really mean `alignof(void*)`, not `sizeof`; otherwise with the hypothetical 3-byte size_t referred to above, the padding computation will be incorrect. `alignof` *is* guaranteed to be a power of two, so the arithmetical fix is unnecessary after the change.

Comment: `size_t` holds the size of the largest possible object. On a machine where addresses are segment/offset with 24-bit offsets, a 24 bit size_t would be acceptable. Storing that in three bytes is another question.

Comment: @rici OK now I remembered... the one machine with 1's complement representation had a 72 bit unsigned long long value with 2^72 - **2** as the maximum... that would still break the modulo.

Comment: I don't think 2^36-2 is a valid maximum for an unsigned type.

Comment: @rici it isn't compliant for sure

Comment: It's not that it *could* use alignof. It must use alignof; if sizeof a pointer is not a power of two, using sizeof will produce the wrong answer.

Comment: @rici actually, if `sizeof (void *)` is `3`, its alignment requirement must be 1... so aligning by 3 would *still* be aligned; same for 6; the alignment requirement is either 1 or 2 and the code would still produce a correct alignment, but in some cases with extra padding, even with the wraparound subtraction

Comment: Ok. You can get away with sizeof but alignof is correct. And I see you edited the answer so we're good.